# PHP - If statement comparing string with contents of txt file

Tags: php, if-statement, string-comparison

I did some research and couldn't find a clear answer to my problem. This is what I have:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $gen_num = file_get_contents($_SESSION['filename']);
    $inp_num = $_POST['form-input'];
    if($gen_num === $inp_num){
        echo "Yes! The numbers match!";
    } else {
        echo "No, the numbers do not match&hellip;";
    }
?>
```

Where the 'filename' has a string of numbers and 'form-input' is carried from a previously submitted HTML form.

Why does the IF test fail when the strings are identical?

EDIT
The simple fix was trimming the $gen_num. Also, I wasn't specific enough in saying that the 'filename' was a .txt file that included a string of numbers along with some unseen special characters.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you `var_dump()` both and show us what you get?

Comment: Have you tried just using == for your comparison? http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Try `trim($gen_num) === trim($inp_num)` as the occurrence of special characters might be the issue.

Comment: *Where the 'filename' has a string of numbers*... So there is no `.txt`? I'm quite sure it file_get_contents returns false then

Comment: One thing to check - `$_SESSION['filename']` might indeed reference the filename correctly but `file_get_contents()` will look in same directory as your PHP script if no full path specified as 1st parameter. I.e is your text file located in the same folder as your PHP script?

Comment: The trim() worked! I guess there was some white space/special characters mucking it up. Thank you for the quick response everyone

Answer (score 0):

If `$_SESSION['filename']` is as you say a string of numbers then there is no file name ending.
You should make that line:

```
$gen_num = file_get_contents($_SESSION['filename'] . ".txt");
```

Or file_get_contents won't find a file with only numbers as the name and return false.
That is why the numbers don't match.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The 'filename' was set up to capture the '.txt' inside the variable (i.e. filename = something.txt)

Comment: In that case $filename does not *has a string of numbers* does it?

Answer (score 0):

If the two values are integers I'd floor() them and use ==

And catch for 0 exception